# how to create a simple python web serivce, that would run locally and handle parallel requests

Tags: python, windows, rest, flask

So, as the header indicates, im trying to understand what is the most simple way to create a rest api web service, that would run locally on my pc, and would be able to handle requests in parallel (just using my several local cores).

I was checking out flask, but im not sure that's the right option. i know by default it runs with a single instance, and it has an option of using a "process" param, which doesnt work for me and seem not to be the solution.

im looking for something simple, but couldnt find anything.

all i want to be able to do, is be able to receive REST requests and handle them in parallel using a process pool for example.

note: I'm using windows. so gunicorn isn't an option i think

Comment: How about `gunicorn` ?

Comment: The [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/) address this very concern. There are lots of options. Some popular choices are gunicorn and uwsgi.

Comment: @match doesnt work with windows

Comment: I'd added windows as a tag to the question, but you might want to be explicit about that restriction in your question...